# Set audience in iOS6 Facebook sharing sheet?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

Using the stock iOS6 Facebook sharing sheet (`SLComposeViewController`), the audience defaults to "Only Me". Is it possible to make it default to "Friends Only"?

I feel like most people won't even notice that it's set to "Only Me" and wonder why their friends can't see their post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up your iOS6 Facebook account for the very first time, then the default audience setting is "Friends". However, it remembers your last known audience selection. So say the user goes to Safari, shares a link and sets the audience to "Only Me", when they come back to your app, the default is "Only Me". There's no way to change this.

If you want more control you should look into using SLRequest, but you would have to build your own share UI.